# Python - Not getting expected Substring re.sub

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating an script to get the substring from a log, but for some reason I'm not getting the correct one on a specific scenario.

This is my code:

```
import re

value = "null]] PKMS: Sending message: [00136|P|20002000            |001|00001|00002|7385581WS           |7285581 |WS|DPRW      |  |20200121|211703|20200121|211703|                    |]. host[127.0.0.1] port[9014]"

keyword = "P"

print(re.sub(".*%s" % keyword, keyword, value))
```

What I'm trying to do it to get the substring starting from "|P|": 
"P|20002000            |001|00001|00002|7385581WS           |7285581 |WS|DPRW      |  |20200121|211703|20200121|211703| |n]. host[127.0.0.1] port[9014]"

But for some reason the substring I'm getting this: "PRW      |  |20200121|211703|20200121|211703| |n]. host[127.0.0.1] port[9014]"

Not sure what am I'm doing wrong, because if I replace the keyword with the word "PKMS", I get the correct substring. I also tried using "|P|" but I get another result that is also incorrect.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: By default `*` (and `+` and even a lousy `?`) try to match *as much as possible*. That's why it eats up your first Peas -- there is a final one at the far end of your string and that's used to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have been escaping the pipes correctly

```
re.sub(r'.*\|(?=P\|)', '', value)
```

will remove all of the characters up to the last `|` in the string that is followed by `P|`. (`(?=...)` is called a look-ahead)